# How to set footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

This is [the website](http://www.onetechsearch.com/tech/?search=&images=1&from=&to=&cat=all) I'm currently working on and my problem is that I can't seem to find a way in which to set the footer at the bottom of the page under all the elements. I want the footer to have a position:fixed, but for it to be under the next page element that is at the bottom of the page.

Some of the code:

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 1%;
    height: 6%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 70px 0 0 0;
    }

.content-middle {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 56%;
}

.content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: what do you want . be clearly..

Comment: I want for the footer to have a fixed position, but for it to appear under the next page element at the bottom of the page

Comment: Why do you use `position:fixed` for this?

Comment: In order for the footer to always appear on the page, and not just when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page

Comment: Now I understand what you tryin' to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update Style** using `margin-bottom`

```
   #pagination 
   {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0.4% 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #999;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
   }
```

***Add remove White space then update style using***  `height: auto !important;`. because after your search result your `li or class="reteta"` set `height:350px`

```
#retete.simple-style li.reteta {
    width: 98%;
    max-width: 680px;
    min-width: 280px;
    height: auto !important;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

***or other wise only simple add style***

```
#retete.simple-style li.reteta {        
        height: auto !important;
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you help with one extra thing? When u go on the website and select "no pictures" and then search, the result have a very big space between them. Anyway I can fix that?

Comment: why not . i try it

Comment: It's working, I was just wondering if u can help me with one extra issue I have?

Comment: If you go on [my website](http://www.onetechsearch.com/tech/category/all/?search=&images=0&to=&cat=all), you can see that there is huge space between every item. How can I fix that?

Comment: this problem solve it updated my answer plz check it and update this `#retete.simple-style li.reteta` style .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a `margin-bottom: 90px; to #pagination.`

```
#pagination {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a bottom: 0px; to footer

```
#footer {
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px
text-align: center;
bottom: 1%;
height:6%;
width: 100%;
padding:2%;
z-index:500;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

The only diff is **bottom:0px;** .Try this